# AtomPub - What's your recommendation?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services, atompub

I'm looking to create a service (based on .NET Fx 3.5 or 4.0) that exposes data via Atom and enables AtomPub (so that I can update using Windows Live Writer).

There looks to be two options:

- Use ADO.NET Data Services.  From what I can tell this is the easiest to get working, but requires EF (I'm using LinqToSQL - although I know there is a workaround) and mapping the types seems a little inflexible.  e.g. I still don't know how to remove elements from the feed.
- Do something custom with a WCF Syndication Feed.  This looks like the most flexible approach, but is of course custom, and will require more coding.

I'm interested in opinions from people that have implemented AtomPub in their own applications.  Which approach did you use?  (or did you do something different?)

Comment: The mapping of types in a Data Service is only as inflexible as its underlying data source. What are some examples of issues you're running into?

Also, to remove an item from a feed, you would simply make an HTTP DELETE request to the URI of the element you wanted to delete (e.g. Customers(23)), or if you're using the generated proxy client, it would handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using BlogSvc:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=75291315-f7aa-418a-b18d-2c10defa8bc1

> Since the project uses Atom and
>   AtomPub he can work against it using
>   Windows Live Writer. You can learn all
>   about how WLW likes Atom by reading
>   the series of posts the most excellent
>   Joe Cheng of the Live Writer team did
>   on how this is all implemented.